# How to abort a python instance creaction and continue the script?

Tags: python, instantiation

I implemented a python class for which the instances are stored in a h5-file. As such, the `__init__()`-function of this class first checks if this h5-file yet exists from a previous simulations, and if so raises a raw_input asking to overwrite this file (whereafter the file is overwritten by the new instance) or not, whereafter an error is raised.

I am looking for a way that, when this file (and thus instance) already exists and this is noted in the `__init__()`-method, i don't raise an Error whereafter the script stops, buta way to "cancel" the started instantiation and the script just continues ... Is there a clean way to implement such "cancel and ocntinue" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do it *is* to raise an exception. By default, the exception will propagate out from the `__init__` to whoever called it, and eventually all the way to the top, halting the script.

But if you want to handle that exception and continue, use a `try`/`catch` block at whatever level you want to continue from, as described in [Handling Exceptions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

For example:

```
class ThingyAlreadyExistsError(RuntimeError):
    pass

class Thingy(object):
    def __init__(self, pathname):
        if os.path.exists(pathname):
            yn = raw_input('{} already exists. Overwrite (y/N)?'.format(pathname))
            if yn.lower != 'y':
                raise ThingyAlreadyExistsError(pathname)
        # finish initialization

thingies = []
for pathname in pathnames:
    try:
        thingy = Thingy(pathname)
    except ThingyAlreadyExistsError:
        continue
    thingies.append(thingy)
```

If you want to catch this before even getting to the `__init__`, you could always do the check in the `__new__` method, or in a `@classmethod` factory function, or in the `for` loop, in which case you don't even need an exception; just don't initialize. But there's nothing stopping you from raising an exception inside `__init__`.

Comment: Can i define this 'pass' command in the 'class ThingAlreadyExistsError(Exception)' so that raising this error automatically results in passing on with the script ?

Comment: @rubenbaetens: I don't understand your question. You can't define `pass`; it's a built-in statement that means "do nothing". Anyway, it doesn't matter what type of exception you raise; you have to catch it with an `except` statement. (How would Python know what you wanted to skip and what you wanted to continue, if you didn't tell it?)